# listview does not show anything

Tags: android, xml, listview

i can not figure out the problem my listview suddenly disappeared. I searched solution and tried every possible change in xml file but i still get the empty screen.
xml for listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

listview items

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/dcode"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="drcode"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:text="docname"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/a"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="43dp"
    android:text="adr"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/adr"
    android:text="class_desc"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvshift"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:text="shift"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tcode"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/docname"
    android:text="terrcode"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
```

code of listview adapter

```
public class planningListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

  Context context;
  public ArrayList<Planning> planArraylist;
  private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
  public Activity attdSetupActivity;

  public planningListViewAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Planning> planArraylist) {
          this.context = context;
          this.planArraylist = planArraylist;
          inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                          .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  }


  @Override
  public int getCount() {
          return planArraylist.size();
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int arg0) {
          return null;
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int arg0) {
          return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          if (convertView == null) {
                  convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_lv_item, null);
          }

          Planning p = planArraylist.get(position);

         TextView tvdrCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dcode);
          TextView tvDrName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dname);
          TextView tvTerr = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tcode);
          TextView tvAdr = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.a);
          TextView tvClassDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cd);
        //TextView tvSpeciality= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.speciaility);
          TextView tvShift = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvshift); 



          tvdrCode.setText(p.getDrCode());
          tvDrName.setText(p.getDocName());
          tvTerr.setText(p.getTerrCode());
          tvAdr.setText(p.getAdr());
          tvClassDesc.setText(p.getClassDesc());
          //tvSpeciality.setText(p.getSpeciality());
         tvShift.setText(p.getShift());

          return convertView;
  }
```

}
Activity code

```
public class PlanningList_activity extends Activity{


 private Db_sqlite dbHelper;
 private planningListViewAdapter dataAdapter;
 private ListView listView;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.planning_listview);

      /*   TextView columnHeader1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.column_header1);
         TextView columnHeader2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.column_header2);
         TextView columnHeader3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.column_header3);
         TextView columnHeader4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.column_header4);
         TextView columnHeader5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.column_header5);
         TextView columnHeader6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.column_header6);


         columnHeader1.setText("Plan No");
         columnHeader2.setText("Plan Date");
         columnHeader2.setText("Mon");
         columnHeader2.setText("Dr Code");
         columnHeader2.setText("Morn_Even");
         columnHeader2.setText("FF_Code"); */

         Log.e("on create", "yes");

         listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
         dbHelper = new Db_sqlite(PlanningList_activity.this);
         new AsyncLoadplanList().execute();
 }

 public class AsyncLoadplanList extends
                 AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Planning>> {

         ProgressDialog progressDialog;

         @Override
         protected void onPreExecute() {
                 progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(PlanningList_activity.this);
                 progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                 progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                 progressDialog.show();
                 Log.e("pre execute", "yes");

         }

         @Override
         public ArrayList<Planning> doInBackground(Void... params) {
                 try {
                         Log.e("In background", "yee");
                         return loadData();

                 } catch (Exception e) {
                         Log.e("get lost", e.getMessage());
                 }
                 return null;
         }

         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Planning> result) {
                 super.onPostExecute(result);

                 dbHelper.close();
                 Log.e("data saving", "yoo");
                 dataAdapter = new planningListViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(),result);
                 listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

                 if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                         progressDialog.dismiss();
                 }

                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "data loaded",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
         }

         private ArrayList<Planning> loadData() {

                 // Load data here from database
                 return dbHelper.getPlanningList();

         }
 }
```

Database method

```
public ArrayList<Planning> getPlanningList() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    ArrayList<Planning> planningList = new ArrayList<Planning>();
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(DOC_PLANNING_TABLE_NAME, null,null,null,null,null,null);
    if (mCursor != null && mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                    Planning planning = new Planning();
                    String docCode = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DCP_COLUMN_dr_code));
                    String planno = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DCP_COLUMN_PLAN_NO));
                   String terrCode = mCursor.getString(mCursor
                                    .getColumnIndex(DCP_COLUMN_terr_code));
                    String adr = mCursor.getString(mCursor
                                    .getColumnIndex(DCP_COLUMN_PLAN_DATE));
                    String classdesc= mCursor.getString(mCursor
                                    .getColumnIndex(DCP_COLUMN_MON));
                    String speciality= mCursor.getString(mCursor
                                  .getColumnIndex(DCP_COLUMN_REF_NO));

                    String shift= mCursor.getString(mCursor
                            .getColumnIndex(DCP_COLUMN_MORN_EVEN)); 

                    planning.setDrCode(docCode);
                    planning.setDocName(planno);
                    planning.setTerrCode(terrCode);
                    planning.setAdr(adr);
                    planning.setClassDesc(classdesc);
                    planning.setShift(shift);
                      planning.setSpeciality(speciality);
            } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
            mCursor.close();
    }
    return planningList;
```

}

I have wasted a lot of time finding the problem but i cannnot understand why it is not showing on the screen. please guide me.

Comment: in which xml file you put your listview?

Comment: @MD sorry.  i have edited the post

Comment: @GulMuhammadAkbari listview is in separate xml file

Comment: where is your activity code?

Comment: On a side note: The `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` you set to your `ListView` is bad in oh so many ways, but mostly it doesn't make any sense. You put the `ListView` there so you can scroll through a bunch of items, right? So if you set its height to `wrap_content` then you are telling the `ListView` to wrap all the content inside it or in other words to be so big that it spans all the items inside it. This will not work and is not supported by the `ListView` in the first place. Give the `ListView` a fixed height like `80dp` or `match_parent`.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_list_view.htm

Comment: @XaverKapeller and what about the width? it should be wrap_content or match_parent?

Comment: What do you think? Do you want the `ListView` to wrap its content? (See my previous comment if you want the answer...)

Comment: @XaverKapeller i changed both attributes to match_parent, but still i cannot see the list

Comment: Well I didn't expect that to fix your problem. It just fixes a few problems you would have had after your current one is solved.

Comment: @MD i have added the activity code

Comment: @konainali Did you confirm that the data is retrieved from the database?

Comment: yeah the data is retrieving correctly. I debugged the code everything went fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct in your code as below:

```
@Override   
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
          return planArraylist.get(planArraylist.get(arg0-1));   }

  @Override   
  public long getItemId(int arg0) {
          return arg0;   }
```

Comment: So did you your issue get fixed?

Comment: Ranjith i used this code and now i'm getting null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think you write you getView method differently and use a holder class, as shown below:

```
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
      return planArraylist.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
      return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_lv_item, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.tvdrCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dcode);
            holder.tvDrName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dname);
            holder.tvTerr = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tcode);
            holder.tvAdr = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.a);
            holder.tvClassDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cd);
            holder.tvShift = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvshift); 

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

          Planning p = planArraylist.get(position);

          holder.tvdrCode.setText(p.getDrCode());
          holder.tvDrName.setText(p.getDocName());
          holder.tvTerr.setText(p.getTerrCode());
          holder.tvAdr.setText(p.getAdr());
          holder.tvClassDesc.setText(p.getClassDesc());
          holder.tvShift.setText(p.getShift());

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
          TextView tvdrCode;
          TextView tvDrName;
          TextView tvTerr;
          TextView tvAdr;
          TextView tvClassDesc;
          TextView tvShift;
    }
```

Also, your list view xml file uses a Linear layout but you have properties that can only be found in a Relative layout such as  `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`. Could you fix that as well?

Comment: actually it was working pretty good it suddenly caused this problem i think the issue is in xml file

Comment: Could you update your xml as I suggested in my updated answer?

Comment: Did you also update the `planningListViewAdapter` with the suggested edits to see if the problem is solved?